# how to save video in ipad simulator

Tags: ios-simulator, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to pick video from photo library using imagePickerController.

but there is no video on my simulator. I know how to load images in simulator but don't know how to load video. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to drag&drop a .mov file to the simulator. Once you do that, you will see the video and you can save it to the camera roll (with one of the buttons displayed in that screen).

But you won't be able to pick the video in the simulator because there is an error while compressing the video.